# Do eigenvectors of a squared matrix A tell us anything about the eigenvectors of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a following task:

> Let $X$ be an eigenvector of $A$.
>
> a) Prove that $X$ is also an eigenvector of $A^2$
>
> b) Is the convere theorem true?

I had no problem with the first part. Ive tried disproving the second part this way:

Let $e$ be the eigenvalue of $A^2$ corresponding to the eigenvector $X$. By definition we know that:

$A^2X=eX \to (A^2-eI)X=0 \to (A-eI)(A+eI)X=0$

If im not mistaken that proves that $X$ is an eigenvector either for $A$ or $-A$ (since $X$ is a nonzero vector). How can I evaluate which of those two matrices share the common eigenvector with $A^2$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The last equation does not show that $X$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: How not? Am I missing something? (Sorry im new to this subject). Even if I assume that both matrices (A-eI) and (A+eI) are nonzero? @Travis Willse

Comment: Having checked a matrix that satisfies the condition given by you I can see that the eigenvector of $A^2$ doesn't necessarily have to mean that either $A$ or $-A$ have the same eigenvector. Would you be so kind and point out where I misunderstood something? Thanks

Comment: Ahh... Of course the determinant of neither of those two matrices: $A-eI$, $A+eI$ has to be zero. Thank you very much!

Comment: It is possible for both $(A - eI) X$ $(A + eI) X$ to be nonzero---so that $X$ is not an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\pm e$---but still to have $(A - eI)(A + eI) X = 0$. (It is not a fatal error, but $(A^2 - e I) X = 0$ can be rewritten as $(A - \mu I)(A + \mu I) X = 0$ for any $\mu$ satisfying $\mu^2 = e$, not as $(A - eI)(A + eI)$.)

Comment: Hm, I'm not quite sure what you mean: If $X$ is nonzero and $(A^2 - \mu^2 I) X = 0$, then $$0 = \det (A^2 - \mu^2 I) = \det [(A - \mu I) (A + \mu I)] = \det (A - \mu I) \det (A + \mu I) ,$$ so the determinant of at least one of the two factors must be zero.

Comment: Try the $2x2$ whose first row is $0 ... 1$ and second row is $ -1 ...  0 $. It has no (non-$0$) real eigenvectors, but it's square has a lot of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

1. Consider a nonzero matrix $A$ whose square is the zero matrix.
2. Alternatively, if you are considering a real matrix $A$ and only considering real eigenvalues, consider a matrix $A$ such that $A^2$ has a negative eigenvalue.

> **Additional hints** Consider, respectively, $$\textrm{(1)} \qquad \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \textrm{(2)} \qquad \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0} .$$

That said, at least for matrices $A$ over an algebraically closed field (like $\Bbb C$), the answer to the titular question is still yes, that knowing the eigenvectors of $A^2$ gives us at least some information about the eigenvectors of $A$:

Considering the Jordan block decomposition of $A$ shows that in this setting, for each eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A^2$ there is at least one eigenvector $\bf v$ of $A^2$ that is an eigenvector of $A$. In particular, if all of the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are distinct, then all of the eigenvectors of $A^2$ are eigenvectors of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}$$
We have $A^2 = I$ so $$A^2\pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0& 1}\pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$$
and therefore $\pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$ is an eigenvector for $A^2$. However,

$$A\pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0}\pmatrix{1 \\ 0} = \pmatrix{0 \\ 1}$$
is not a scalar multiple of $\pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$ so $\pmatrix{1 \\ 0}$ is not an eigenvector for $A$.